# Insert image conditionally in cv template

Tags: templates, friggeri-cv

I have inserted an image in the left margin (Sidebar Section) of a Friggeri CV (see MWE below). My CV is several pages long, but I would like to suppress the image from appearing on 2nd and subsequent pages. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

```
    % Friggeri Resume/CV
    % XeLaTeX Template
    % Version 1.2 (3/5/15) 

    % This template has been downloaded from:
    % https://github.com/mlda065/friggeri-letter
    %
    % Original author: 
    % Adrien Friggeri (adrien@friggeri.net)
    % https://github.com/afriggeri/CV
    %
    % Modifications by Matthew Davis (matthew@mdavis.xyz)
    \documentclass[a4paper]{friggeri-cv} 
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{document} 

    \header{John}{Smith}{Short Statement Here}

    %   SIDEBAR SECTION 
    \aside{{\includegraphics[width=3.2cm]{IMAGE.jpg}}\vspace{0.5cm}\\
    Contact}{
    \ifx \firstPage \undefined
    \xdef\firstPage{}
    \else
    John SMITH \\
    ~ \\
    \fi
    123 Main St. \\
    Toronto, ON\\
    H0H 0H0, Canada \\
    ~  \\
    (416) 555-1212 \\
    ~   \\
    \href{mailto:me@domain.com}{me@domain.com}\\
    }

    % EXPERIENCE SECTION
    \section{Experience}
    \subsection{XYZ Corp.}
    \begin{entrylist}

    \entry 
    {June 2015 -- present}
    {Manager}
    {Toronto}
    {}
    {
    This is a description of the job called 'Manager'. 
    }

    \end{entrylist}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, aside from the fact that `friggeri-cv` is mostly broken, you are using the `aside` environmnt completely wrong. Also, you are not sharing with us which version of the template/class you are using. There are about a dozen version out there, all slightly different and the people who made changes did not leave a freaking note that they modified the class. That is just rude of them.

Comment: I have added version and template data to my original post and will do so in the future. Sorry about that. The aside environment I used in the way shown does yield a nice effect - it puts my contact info on the left side of each page (and leaves my first name and last name off of the first page because it is displayed at the top of the first page). But the picture (\includegraphics...) shows up on every page, and that is what my original post asks - how to make that image in the aside environment appear on the first page only.

Answer (score 1):

What is used here is a modification of the original template, and like it happens so  often, not a single name change is made.

two possible solutions:

```
% Friggeri Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (3/5/15) 

% This template has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/mlda065/friggeri-letter
%
% Original author: 
% Adrien Friggeri (adrien@friggeri.net)
% https://github.com/afriggeri/CV
%
% Modifications by Matthew Davis (matthew@mdavis.xyz)
\documentclass[a4paper]{friggeri-cv} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document} 

\header{John}{Smith}{Short Statement Here}

            %   SIDEBAR SECTION 
\begin{textblock}{3.6}(2,12)
{\includegraphics[width=3.2cm]{example-image-1x1}}
\end{textblock}
\aside{Contact}{
                \ifx \firstPage \undefined
                \xdef\firstPage{}
                \medbreak
                \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-1x1}
                \medbreak
                \else
                John SMITH \\
                ~ \\
                \fi
                123 Main St. \\
                Toronto, ON\\
                H0H 0H0, Canada \\
                ~  \\
                (416) 555-1212 \\
                ~   \\
                \href{mailto:me@domain.com}{me@domain.com}\\
            }

                                                % EXPERIENCE SECTION
            \section{Experience}
            \subsection{XYZ Corp.}
            \begin{entrylist}

                \entry 
                {June 2015 -- present}
                {Manager}
                {Toronto}
                {}
                {
                    This is a description of the job called 'Manager'. 
                }

            \end{entrylist}
            \clearpage
                                                % EXPERIENCE SECTION
            \section{Experience}
            \subsection{XYZ Corp.}
            \begin{entrylist}

                \entry 
                {June 2015 -- present}
                {Manager}
                {Toronto}
                {}
                {
                    This is a description of the job called 'Manager'. 
                }

            \end{entrylist}
            \end{document}
```

Renaming files to make clear that they are not identical would be a much better way.